# Struct in member function cannot new address of it's

Tags: c++, struct, template-meta-programming

Main class creates instance for running the tire class. Tire class calls a member functions `bool tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>::add_node(TypeTire const& input_data)` in order to push all a characters "ABCDEFAB"  to vector by  `node_root_vec.push_back(node_data);`. The `node_data` creating by `node_data =  new node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>();` before push to vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace boost;

template<typename TypeTire, typename TypeNode>
struct node_tire {
    // data in node
    TypeNode const *data;

    int addr_node;
    // address insert next  node
    std::vector<node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode> > addr_next_node;
    // address insert pervious node
    std::vector<node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode> > addr_prve_node;
    // insert data to node
    node_tire() : data(NULL) { }
};


template<typename TypeTire, typename TypeNode>
class tire
{
    public:
        tire( );
        node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode> *check_node(node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>&   node);
        bool add_node(TypeTire const& data);

    private:

        node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>   *node_data;
        std::vector<node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>* > node_root_vec;

        // handling node
        std::vector<shared_ptr<node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode> > > node_root_shared_ptr;
        typedef shared_ptr<node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode> > node_ptr;

};

template<typename TypeTire, typename TypeNode>
tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>::tire()
{

}

// Finding data in root node before travelling in branch.
template<typename TypeTire, typename TypeNode>
node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode> *tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>::check_node(node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>& node)
{
    int index_root_node = 0;

    for(typename std::vector<node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>* >::iterator iter_root = node_root_vec.begin();
            iter_root != node_root_vec.end();
            ++iter_root, ++index_root_node) {
        node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode> *node_in_vec = *iter_root;
        TypeNode const *data = node_in_vec->data;

        std::cout<<" Compare : " << *data << " : " << *node.data <<", Data address : " << &data <<std::endl;

        if( *data == *node.data) {
            node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>   *node_in_root = node_root_vec[index_root_node];
            std::cout<<"Address fond node in root : " << &node_root_vec[index_root_node] <<", value : " << node_in_root->data <<std::endl;
            return node_root_vec[index_root_node];

        }

    }

    return NULL;
}

template<typename TypeTire, typename TypeNode>
bool tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>::add_node(TypeTire const& input_data)
{
    int index_input = 0;

    for(typename TypeTire::const_iterator iter_input = input_data.begin(); iter_input != input_data.end(); ++iter_input, ++index_input) {

        node_data =  new node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>();
        node_data->data  =  &(*iter_input);
        std::cout<<" Node Address : " << &node_data <<std::endl;

        // Found data in root node in condition else.
        // Not found in root node to if.
        if(check_node(*node_data) == NULL) {
            node_root_vec.push_back(node_data);
        }

    }

}

// mian.cpp
int main()
{
tire<std::string, char> tire_node;
std::string str_test = "ABCDEFAB";
tire_node.add_node(str_test);
}
```

I print address of `node_data` releases from vector which it should new address of `node_data`, but show only old address after create by `node_data =  new node_tire<TypeTire, TypeNode>();`. Why cannot new address of `node_data`?

```
 Node Address : 0x7fff0ebb28b0
 Node Address : 0x7fff0ebb28b0
 Compare : A : B, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Node Address : 0x7fff0ebb28b0
 Compare : A : C, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : B : C, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Node Address : 0x7fff0ebb28b0
 Compare : A : D, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : B : D, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : C : D, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Node Address : 0x7fff0ebb28b0
 Compare : A : E, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : B : E, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : C : E, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : D : E, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Node Address : 0x7fff0ebb28b0
 Compare : A : F, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : B : F, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : C : F, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : D : F, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Compare : E : F, Data address : 0x7fff0ebb2760
 Node Address : 0x7fff0ebb28b0
```

Answer (score 0):

See my code and may be you get you error quickly:

```
void test() {
    int n;
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        n = i + 2;
        std::cout << "Address of n is: " << &n << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Do you think that output of my program should changed? I change value of `n` but I can't change its address, can I?
As in your case you are changing value of `node_data`, but you can never change address of `node_data`. can you? and what you are printing is address of `node_data` and not its value.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing &node_data, which is the adress of the  node_data member, which is a constant offset of your tire object adress.

tha adress of allocated instance is node_data (the one on which you made the new)